# Zorns Lemma to prove there is an minimal element

Tags: general-topology

Prove: If every totally ordered subset of an ordered set $X$ has a lower bound in $X$, then $X$ has a minimal element.

Proof: Let $X,\le$ be a partially ordered set. Also let, $x,y\in X$,
$$
x\preceq y \text{ if and only if } y\le x
$$
Then $\preceq$ is a partial order on $X$, $$\text{ i.) Reflexive: x x\preceq x \text { means } x\leq x \text{ but } x-x\leq 0 \Rightarrow 0\leq 0 \text{ but } 0 \nless 0, \text{ so the reflexive property is not satisfied }.$$

$$\text{ ii.) Symmetric: } x\preceq y \text{ means } y\le x and y\preceq y \text{ means } x\le y \text{ multiplying together we get } xy\preceq yx \text{ means } yx\le xy \text { which satisfies the symmetric property.$$
I would continue but I am not sure if this part is right, I really have a hard time using zorns lemma to prove anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation you define is the *opposite relation* of the given one.

It is reflexive: since for any $x\in X$ you have $x\le x$, then $x\preceq x$ as well.

It is antisymmetric. If $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq x$, then $y\le x$ and $x\le y$, so $x=y$.

It is transitive. If $x\preceq y$ and $y\preceq z$, then $z\le y$ and $y\le x$, so $z\le x$ and therefore $x\preceq z$.

It is almost obvious that an element is $\le$-maximal if and only if it is $\preceq$-minimal and similarly for all other properties ($\le$-maximum becomes $\preceq$-minimum, $\le$-minimal becomes $\preceq$-maximal and so on). Just apply the definitions.